# How do you duplicate an aframe-room-component in a DRY fashion?

Tags: duplicates, dry, aframe

I'm trying to create many buildings using aframe-room-component. Is there a more DRY way to duplicate the rw-room entities than the method I'm currently using (literally just adding multiple rw-room's.

I've looked into writing a component in index.js, but I get confused by trying to incorporate the aframe-room-component.

```
<rw-room outside="true" position="0 0 -10" material="color: #866; side: double">
        <rw-ceiling></rw-ceiling>
        <rw-floor></rw-floor>
        <rw-wall position="4 0 0"></rw-wall>
        <rw-wall position="4 0 4"></rw-wall>
        <rw-wall position="0 0 4"></rw-wall>
        <rw-wall position="0 0 0">
            <rw-doorhole id="holeA"></rw-doorhole>
            <rw-doorlink from="#holeA" to="#holeB" position="2.5 0 0"></rw-doorlink>
        </rw-wall>
      </rw-room>
      <rw-room outside="true" side="double" position="4 0 -2" material="color: #866; side: double">
          <rw-wall position=" 1 0  1"  side="double" material="color:#877; side: double">
              <rw-doorhole id="holeB"></rw-doorhole>
          </rw-wall>
      </rw-room>

      <rw-room outside="true" position="-3 0 -10" rotation="0 180 0" material="color: #866; side: double">
          <rw-ceiling></rw-ceiling>
          <rw-floor></rw-floor>
          <rw-wall position="4 0 0"></rw-wall>
          <rw-wall position="4 0 4"></rw-wall>
          <rw-wall position="0 0 4"></rw-wall>
          <rw-wall position="0 0 0">
              <rw-doorhole id="holeC"></rw-doorhole>
              <rw-doorlink from="#holeC" to="#holeD" position="2.5 0 0"></rw-doorlink>
          </rw-wall>
        </rw-room>
        <rw-room outside="true" side="double" position="4 0 -2" material="color: #866; side: double">
            <rw-wall position=" 1 0  1"  side="double" material="color:#877; side: double">
                <rw-doorhole id="holeD"></rw-doorhole>
            </rw-wall>
        </rw-room>
```

Hope this is clear enough and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's like:

- The A-Frame template component https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-template-
  component.
- Or have a component that dumps into innerHTML as a string, building the template using regex or string replace. The string could optionally be defined via `<template>` tag.